# Error: a value of type "double*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double"

Tags: c++

I encountered a problem while i type my code.

```
...
double* FindMax(const double* const arr, int n)
{
    double max;
    ...
    return &max;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    maxVal = FindMax(value, numbers);
    ...
}
```

When I call the function FindMax, the program error and not allow me pass the value to function FindMax.
How can I make it possible, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to return a pointer rather than the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things, if `maxVal` is double, you cannot assign value of `&max`. It should be `double *`.
 Secondly, never return address of local variable. Because once you return from function, local variable die.

Comment: The first is right.
But could you explain second problem more?

Comment: how to got the value of max?

Comment: Just `return max`, there is no need to return address if you just want value.

Comment: @user3371061 More specifically, `FindMax` should return double, not `double *`

Comment: @user3371061 Yes, I am suggesting change function type to `double` and return `double *`